# How to find that “cpu” hardware is 32 bit or 64 bit, if the system displays “i686”?

Tags: 64-bit, cpu, 32-bit, architecture

Is my hardware 64 bit or 32 bit?

This is the output of my lscpu command:

```
Mint ~ # lscpu
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 60
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               3498.029
BogoMIPS:              6996.05
Hypervisor vendor:     VMware
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
```

As you can see my architecture is the 32-bit i686. But it also has both 32 and 64 bit op-modes. How is this possible.

Also, in /proc/cpuinfo you can see lm is listed

```
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm arat xsaveopt fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2
```

So is my CPU 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong: Are you running Linux MInt in a virtual machine (VMware)? In that case, what is the host operating system? You need the corresponding data for the host operating system, that runs in hardware in order to get correct data about the hardware.

Comment: Yes I am. I know what hardware the host is running. What can I glean from the information given? Am I running a virtual 64-bit cpu or a virtual 32-bit cpu? Sorry if that's a dumb question.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: PAE is 64-bit memory addressing (*physical address extensions*) and was available for 32-bit (x86) AND 64-bit (x86_64) machines.. Microsoft said it would be available for XP SP2 (32-bit), but it got delayed, delayed & eventually abandoned b/c of bugs they never solved. In the *linux* world your architecture is i686, but 64bit or 32bit what?  Intel/AMD narrow it down with more precision   (i386 in debian terms as i386-i686 are treated equal for ISOs), however Mint is off-topic here (not Ubuntu, nor flavor of Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

i686 means you are using a 32 bit OS.
In the terminal type `uname -a`. This is due to there are versions of CPU that can address more than 4GB (2^32) of ram. But this doesn't make the CPU 64 bit.

You can have look at this answer. This question has been answered in detail here:
[32-bit, 64-bit CPU op-mode on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77718/32-bit-64-bit-cpu-op-mode-on-linux).

I hope this helps.